# Why can't I set values to spinner in android

Tags: android

I have a Class which when it executes, displays this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.onth/com.example.onth.Savedlocation}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This is my code:

```
package com.example.onth;

import java.util.List;
import org.w3c.dom.Comment;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Savedlocation extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

           Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
            List<locationprofl> loc = db.getAlllocation();  
            String log = " ";

            for (locationprofl cn : loc) {
                 log ="lat: "+cn.getlat()+" long:"+cn.getlong()+" ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Profile: " + cn.getProfile();
                 Log.v("aaa", log);

            }
            final Spinner dropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            String[] items = new String[]{"General", "Silent", "Outdoor"};
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
            dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
            //addListenerOnButton();    

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.savedlocation, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: post the complete log

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the content to the activity. (setContentView missing).

```
final Spinner dropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

dropdown  will be null, since you have not set the view to the activity

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your spinner is null.
You need to set a view for this activity, otherwise `findViewById` won't find your spinner.

Add `setContentView(R.layout.yourLayoutFile);` after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `setContentView();`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.location_saved); //You forgot this line
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    ...  

}
```